# Want to click refresh button in my user app

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I am new to Appium using javascript, I want to click the refresh button in my user app

I expect the page should refresh.
but it gives an error
I think I am not able to find the refresh button.
how to find it?

Comment: What error does it give?